# How to get skill Id within a handler with node.js and Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I want to get the Skill Id that is being sent by Alexa to my lambda function but I don't know how to access it within a handler.
context.systen.session.application.applicationid is not working because I don't have the context or a event object.

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    //????????????????how do I get the skill ID here?????????????? 
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Test Test')
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const skillId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.application.applicationId;
```